# (ASP.NET) How do I remove special characters when doing a DateTime.Now.ToString()

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript, string-formatting

So I have a flashobject which I need to pass a formatted DateTime string to.

My code:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

which outputs as: 2009-09-16 22:26:45

However when it is actually output to HTML and swfobject it renders it as:

```
so.addVariable("inNowDate","2009-09-16+22%3a25%3a13");
```

I think this is messing up a calculation that the flash object does based off the current time.  Do I need to encode or decode this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you have gained special characters, but rather certain special characters you already had are now [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

There's not enough information present for me to see exactly where this URL encoding his happening.  Can you post a bit more context?

Comment: I think the problem is i'm using a flash control called BeWise.  I add the variables to it and I'm guessing it's doing the encoding.  I've tried to UrlDecode in my codebehind but they still output like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you output to html, try using UrlDecode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Comment: tried URL decode.  I'm wondering if the control i'm adding the variables too is doing the decoding.

Comment: Perhaps the function has a decode option?  e.g. so.AddVariable(x, "2000...", true)?  Or check anywhere in the api of the swfobject for a decode option.